# Is the nature of God the father like that of Abraham the father of Isaac?

Tags: abraham, god-the-father

Abraham sacrificed his child Isaac not himself because he loved God so much.

Similarly God the father loved his creation so much that he sacrificed his son instead of himself.

Does that mean they are of similar nature?

Was Abraham's sacrifice of Isaac a precursor to God's sacrifice of Jesus Christ?

Comment: More like Abraham is a father like God is father!

Comment: Abraham is considered a minor YHWH by the jewish people, God's chosen!

Answer (score 1):

Saint John Chrysostom (349 - 407) confirms your opinion in "[Homilies on the Gospel of John](https://azbyka.ru/otechnik/Ioann_Zlatoust/homilies-on-the-gospel-of-john/)", 55, 2:

> "Your father Abraham rejoiced to see My day, and he saw it, and was glad" (John 8:56)
>
> My day, seems to me to mean the day of the Crucifixion, which Abraham foreshowed typically by the offering of the ram and of Isaac. ...
>
> He saw My day, and was glad. He shows, that not unwillingly He came to His Passion, since He praises him who was gladdened at the Cross. For this was the salvation of the world.

Comment: Thank you brother in faith.